# Update GUI from Application Class

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

I am trying to show logs on a overlay over all activities. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19037235/3370924 answer which implements the overlay in the application class. I have added a TextView to the LinearLayout to show my logs.

At first it works but then I get the error  `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` 

when I have opened a new Activity and I am trying to add a new string to the TextView.

Usually i use runOnUiThread() but this method is not available in Application class. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Register your activities, in your Application class if you need this, It's bad practice but you should be able to access the view from the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we pretend that your `TextView` is called `tv`, do:

```
tv.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // put your update-the-TextView code here
  }
});
```